# mongodb array data store using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have to try to store my child info into MongoDB via using postman tool. But it shows me this message "message": "child info validation failed"
in postman console. child info is my collection name where I store my child info.

my requirement is to store the result in array form as below schema mentioned inside MongoDB

1). This is js child schema

```
   userId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User'
          },
   quiz:[
        {
        questionId:{
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'questions'
                    },
        score:{type:String},
        time:{type:String}
        }
      ]
```

2). This is node js

```
    try {

            var quizArr = [];
            var quizObj = {
                'questionId': req.params.questionId,
                'score': req.params.score,
                'time': new Date().toISOString()
            };
            quizArr.push(quizObj);
            var userObj = {
                'userid': req.params.userId,
                'quiz': quizArr
            };
            //var parseObj = Json.stringify(userObj);  This line is comment

            var childinfoSave = new QuizChildInfo(userObj);

            childinfoSave.save(function (err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.send("Child questionId score and date saved successfully")
                console.log("Child questionId score and date saved successfully");
            });
      }catch(err){console.log(err);}
```

3). Output of postman screen

```
 {
  "message": "childinfos validation failed"
 }
```

4). Output of console

```
    Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

5). Mongo console

```
     {
     "_id" : ObjectId("57bc483169e718642ac0ac44"),
     "levelsAttempted" : [ ],
     "quiz" : [ ],
     "__v" : 0
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of your console,

put `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` in the file where you have established your server connection( like in my case its `index.js`).

And i think you may have not posted the whole code as i couldnt find `childinfos` in your code.

Comment: childinfos is collection name in child schema where these values get store

Comment: did you fix the promise issue you are facing and re run the API?

Comment: Thanks yes promise issue is remove.but it had created an empty array

Comment: how I have insert value inside this array

Comment: .push() can be used here and as i can see, you are already using it, so you need to debug the code so that you can determine what data you are parsing to db